# What should I do with my answers to locked or low-quality questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, locked-posts

On occasion, I answer a question, and then one of the following happens:

- The question gets locked or put on hold.
- I decide it isn’t a good question and flag to close, but it remains open.

It seems to me that if a question does not belong on the site, then its answers probably don’t belong there either. But I already answered the question and possibly received up votes.

What should I do in these situations? I have deleted a couple of my old answers, losing some rep. Right now I have another answer on a question that is on hold, although that answer isn’t up voted, so I wouldn’t lose much by deleting it.

It somehow doesn’t seem right to collect that extra rep for answers to questions that should have been deleted, but I don’t know whether I should delete my answers to locked/poor questions or just leave them.

### Update

It seems that there is no one-size-fits-all solution for this problem, but perhaps the meta effect can help here: I feel like [Bash script, if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022817/bash-script-if-statement) has been open for far too long. I undeleted my answer so that you can chortle at my folly in answering it. Anyone who would like to review that question (or the answers) and take appropriate action, feel free.

And if trying to invoke the meta effect is a transgression, then please inform me of that fact.

Comment: Don't delete your answers. Try to edit and improve them. [Self-deleted posts contribute to post-bans.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: yes, it's to prevent abuse by users so that users think before posting answers, else we can post anything as an answer and delete it after some time. It's a good thing your answers didn't get downvotes. In future, someone might upvote it if they find it useful.

Comment: If I come across such a bad question which is closed and is highly unlikely to help anyone but the OP, I might downvote your answer with single upvote  (*if it is not accepted*) just so that the question ends up where it deserves to be (*in the hands of roomba*). I'm such a bad guy!!! note that the deletion of answer in this way will not count towards a ban (*as per my knowledge*).

Comment: @TJ I think that's a rude thing to do. If the answer is otherwise right and correct, downvoting the work of someone else is not right. The question may be bad but if someone figured out what was being asked and put in effort to help out the OP, downvoting it is just wrong.

Comment: @xxbbcc An answer can be right and correct and still be utterly useless.

Comment: @xxbbcc they in most cases, did the wrong thing - they should've downvoted and voted to close the *very bad, too localized question with no effort* rather than wasting their time with it... That's just my point of view.

Comment: @yellowantphil Well, I did mean what I said for correct answers. If you feel that your answer is not useful than you should edit it (or not post it in the first place if you're not sure about the answer).

Comment: @TJ I'm not disagreeing with that but once the answer is there, I don't think it deserves a downvote (if it's a useful, correct answer, that is). I'd certainly doiwnvote the question and VTC it. I did stumble upon useful tidbits tied to bad questions in the past.

Comment: @xxbbcc I'm thinking more like the user is promoting such bad questions by providing quick answers. The OP will happily come back with same kind of questions over and over again with no research effort. And I confess that I have done this in the past. But seeing all the extremely low quality questions over the time my mindset became like this. That is why I myself told I'm a bad guy!! :)

Comment: @xxbbcc It seems there will always be some people on this site who downvote correct answers because they don't like the question.  In my experience, such people don't listen to reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jarrod’s answer discusses why it is bad idea to answer very poor questions, but does not directly address what to do if you have already answered such a question.

It seems that there is no official policy on when you should delete your own answers, but usual practice is to avoid deleting them. Once an answer is posted, it is up to other people to up-vote or down-vote your answer on its own merits. Also, the system may factor in numerous self-deleted answers in deciding whether to ban you from posting in the future. The best practice is to refrain from posting answers on very poor or off-topic questions. Instead, vote, flag, or comment on the question as appropriate.

But what if you already posted an answer to a question that should have been deleted, rather than answered? First, flag or vote to close the question. Next, you have a few options:

- See if you get the system to delete the question for you, with some combination of deleting your own answer (if up-voted) and voting down the question. The criteria for automatic deletion are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).
- If that won’t work, you could try finding other people to vote to close the question, either in chat or on meta. This may not work, if other people think more highly of the question or answers than you do.
- If neither one of those options works, you can just choose whether or not to delete your answer.

Comment: This is pretty convoluted. If you believe your answer shouldn't be on SO just delete it. No need to involve others. Sensible people, who take care that their posts are of good quality are not in danger of being answer banned and the new system ensures that you get plenty of warnings before you are banned.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of answering questions that are obviously off-topic and/or guaranteed to be duplicates, which most of the "on hold" questions are nowadays, spend the time instead on finding a duplicate and voting to close on the duplicate.

And if it is an extremely obvious duplicate, downvote the question as well, and if a bunch of [rep whores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522) answer immediately with short technically correct but useless answers while you are looking for the best duplicate link, downvote every one of them.

There is no such thing as a "useful" answer to a useless question and answering these inane questions and/or upvoting answers to things that should obviously be closed as off-topic or duplicates just **makes you part of the problem**.

Downvote answers to these questions; you eventually get the reputation points back when the question gets deleted.

**Hell, who cares about the reputation points if the site devolves into nothing but crap? No one will care what your reputation points is because it will not mean anything. The context will be lost!**

Comment: post a list of them here and we can all go down vote them and give you some incentive ;-p That is why the call it "the meta effect"!

Comment: It's fine to suggest finding duplicates and all that, but no one is *required* to do that. I disagree with downvoting correct answers.

Comment: @user000001 http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif

Comment: @user000001 - I guess you agree with the assertion that breaking windows is good for the economy because it creates business for those that replace them? No action is the exact same as condoning negative behavior, if you aren't part of the solution you are part of the problem.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson If your problem is that the question doesn't get deleted, you can vote to delete the question. You can even flag it if it is that bad and you are under 10K. It's not necessary to punish people that try to be helpful.

Comment: @user000001 The rep loss from the downvotes will be reverted when the question and answer are deleted by the cleanup script. So it's not a punishment, it's cleaning up the site. I personally don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @user000001 - intention has nothing to do with effect. Hell is paved with good intentions, so is the complete devolution of SO. The problem is with the "summer of love" culture that "every question is a special snowflake" is BS. The selfish outnumber those that care, by promoting apathy and selfishness you are part of the problem, **it is everyone's duty as part of a community to aggressively defend the quality of the community and actively reject those that disrespect it**.

Comment: @yellowantphil Re your answer my only comment would be that the dollar sign inside the double parenthesis is not necessary, and that you could also show the case statement with `y|Y`. Otherwise it is definitely not delete-worthy.

Comment: A question being duplicate does not make it useless (since clearly others have had the same question). Further, an answer to a duplicate question may be higher quality than answers for the original question or reflect new information. The suggestion to down vote all answers to a duplicate sounds a bit heavy-handed, especially without regard to the quality of the answers and considering that you've only *voted* to close (so the question is not yet identified as a duplicate, just a potential duplicate).

Comment: @MichaelPetito Since Mr. Roberson wields a dupe-hammer in the `java` tag, he's not voting to close, but effectively closing the question, leaving the serially downvoted answers virtually no chance to recover.